# VisualStudio 2010 - no more automatic precompiled headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

There was a compiler option /YX in visualStudio6 to generate automatically precompiled headers. There was no need for stdafx.h/cpp files, the PCH file was generated automatically from CPP headers with or without the #pragma hdrstop  directive.

The automatic PCH (/YX) appears to be missing in visual studio 2010. Only /Yc (create) or /Yu (use) available.

Anybody know a way to get it back ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [removed in Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177253(v=vs.80).aspx). I'll have to dig for the reason but I suspect features like parallel compilation didn't work well with automatic precompiled headers.

BTW 2010 is an old version of Visual Studio. If you want to work with the most compliant (and faster) compiler , you should use Visual Studio 2013. The [Professional version](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) is free although it's called "Community" nowadays. It supports C++ and all the features that were part of Professional editionsin previous versions.

You'll get much faster compiles from parallel compilation support than automatic precompiled headers. The difference in speed, compliance, library support and debugging between 2010 and 2013 is huge.

**UPDATE**

I found the [announcement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177253(v=vs.80).aspx) and the reason was that there was no improvement by automatic precompiled headers over simply not using them. It was faster (and more stable) to create them once with /Yc then reuse them with /Yu

Answer (score 2):

/YX has been deprecated. You must use /Yc and /Yu instead.

[Microsoft states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4bcz65t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): "If you remove /YX from your build configurations and replace it with nothing, it can result in faster builds."

Basically no time was being saved because more often than not the /YX was guessing wrong. So the added overhead was simply a waste.